# Is this the correct implementation of Randomized Quicksort?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

```
#Randomized Quick Sort
import random
def partition(array , low , high):
   i = low - 1
   pivot = array[high]

   for j in range( low , high):

       if array[j] <= pivot:

           i += 1
           array[i],array[j] = array[j],array[i] # Swapping 

   arr[i+1],arr[high] = arr[high],arr[i+1] 
   return(i+1)
def QuickSort(array,low,high):

   if low < high:
       random_value = random.randint(low,high)
       array[random_value] , array[high] = array[high], array[random_value] 
       mid = partition(array,low,high)
       QuickSort(array,low,mid-1)
       QuickSort(array,mid+1,high)

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
n = len(arr)
QuickSort(arr,0,n-1)
print ("Sorted array is:")
for i in range(n):
   print (arr[i])
```

I have implemented the Randomized Quick sort Algorithm with python. But I am not sure whether it is correct or not. Also , Is there any way we can check the time complexity of both, the normal quicksort and the randomized quick sort with some dataset?

Thankyou

Comment: This is a fantastic opportunity to learn about [unit tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html). If you don't know if your implementation is correct, write some unit tests that use your `QuickSort` function and test whether the result matches your expected output

Comment: Thank-You very much for your response. Actually the above code is correctly providing the sorted array. But I am getting the same answer from the non-randomized quick sort too (Which is quite obvious). My doubt is , I am not able to identify whether this implementation will provide a worst case of O(nlogn). The normal quick-sort on the other hand is about O(n^2).Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Randomness does not change the fact that quicksort is worst-case O(n²). It makes that outcome less likely for common inputs, such as (mostly) sorted data. QS is expected O(n log n) for random inputs; rather than randomising the selection of the partition, you could equally do a random shuffle (once) before starting, which would effectively make the input random.